# Data display for hierarchical data

Tags: hierarchy, data, tree

I have various collections of entities that can be associated at various levels, varying in depth as well.

Would the best approach be to use a treeview? If I cannot use a treeview could I create the UI in such a way that the nesting is evident.

Where can I find good samples of a hierarchical UI?

**UPDATE**

I thought I would give some more detail, and what my specific problem was/is. I have the following sets of entities (from highest in hierarchy to lowest):

- Career Role
- Career Path
- Career Learning Programs
- Certification Collection
- Vendor
- Certification Program
- Certification Exam
- Learning Assets
- Courses

A Career Role in this instance will have several Career Paths associated to it, which is the only association it can have. But a Career Path can be associated to any of the entities below it, at any level. So you could for example have the following structure

**Data Hierarchy Sample**

Say you have a Career Path called "Career Path 1", then you could have the following scenario:

Career Path 1 -> Career Learning Program -> Certification Program -> Certification Exam

Career Path 1 -> Certification Program -> Certification Exam -> Learning Asset -> Course

Career Path 1 -> Course

My problem was that I did not know how to create a consistent display style, because if you apply a particular styling to data lower in the relationship, say course, then that styling will apply at any point, where I would have preferred a style that displays at the current index, not its relationship in the data.

Comment: Can you give more practical information about what kind of data you are working with? And what you want to achieve with showing this data?

Comment: I would have said a tree view is probably the obvious choice, but without more context I can't say for sure.

Comment: There are several questions already on the site about hierarchical data display. Did you review these to see if any of them answer your question before posting? See http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hierarchy

Comment: Depending on your data, Definition Lists can be used to display hierarchy by nesting them, retain their value as DL's, and are easy to put open/close actions on. Depends on your data structure though.

Comment: Wouldn't a screenshot be appropriate here?

Answer (score 2):

Other than Tree View, you can try:

Bread crumbs: http://ui-patterns.com/patterns/Breadcrumbs

Or use a Mac like Column navigation (the correct name escapes me at the moment)

Answer (score 2):

You might try something based on the iPad/iPhone paradigm: a navigation stack moving to the right with optionally, a source list on the left side. Would that work?